# Invoking a ViewComponent within another ViewComponent

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am currently coding within a `ViewComponent` (ViewComponent1) view. Within this View, I have listed a few items: [image: Listed items to be clicked]

As you can see, the channels 11, 12, 13 and 14 are clickable. Each channel has some additional information (OBIS, avtalsid.. etc). What I´m trying to do is to invoke ViewComponent2, within ViewComponent1, and pass along some of the data, based on the clicked item.

What I tried to do is to create another `View` called "Test" and within that `View` invoke ViewComponent2 along with its parameters, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 canalstyle">
        <a asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="Test" asp-route-pod="@item.STATION" 
         asp-route-idnr="@item.IDNR" asp-route-kanal="@item.KANAL" asp-route-start="@Model.start"
         asp-route-end="@Model.end"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KANAL)</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This works, but this method redirects me away from my current `View` (ViewComponent 1). I don't want that. I want the current view to load the additional information from ViewComponent2.

My function that runs the ajax:

```
function myFunction() {

 var data = JSON.stringify({
         'idnr': id,
         'start': this.start,
         'end': this.end
});

 $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("Test2","Customer")',
     type: 'GET',
     data: { idnr: id, start: this.start, end: this.end },
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: handleData(data)
 })
};

function handleData(data) {
    alert(data);
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var $target = $(this).closest("div").find(".details");
    $.get(url, function (res) {
        $target.html(res);
    });
    //do some stuff
}
```

And my Test2 Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test2(string idnr, string start, string end)
{
    ServiceClient r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
    R2S.Konstant[] kData = r2s.GetKonstantListAsync(new string[] { "IDNR" }, new string[] { idnr}).Result; // mätarnummer in... --> alla konstanter kopplade till denna.

    return ViewComponent("MeterReader2", new { k = kData[0], start = start, end = end });
}
```

I am trying to target the same DOM.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is rendering links (a tags) and normally clicking on a link will do a new GET request, which is what you are seeing , the redirect to the new action method.

If you do not want the redirect, but want to show the result of the second view component in same view, you should use ajax.

For example, If you want to show the result of second view component just below each link, you may add another html element for that. Here i am adding an empty div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 canalstyle">
        <a class="myClass" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="DetailsVc" 
                                     asp-route-id="@item.Id" > @item.KANAL</a> 

         <div class="details"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here i just removed all those route params you had in your orignal question and replaced only with on param (`id`) . Assuming your items will have an `Id` property which is the unique id for the record(primary key) and using which you can get the entity (from a database or so) in your view component to get the details.

This will generate the link with css class `myClass`.  You can see that, i used `asp-action` attribute value as "DetailsVc". We cannot directly use the view component name in the link tag helper as attribute value to generate the `href` value. So we should create a wrapper action method which returns your view component result such as below

```
public IActionResult DetailsVc(int id)
{
    return ViewComponent("DetailsComponent", new { id =id });
}
```

Assuming your second view components name is `DetailsComponent` and it accepts an `id` param. Update the parameter list of this action method and view component as needed. (but i suggest passing just the unique Id value and get details in the server code again)

Now all you have to do is have some javascript code which listen to the `click` event on those a tags and prevent the normal behavior (redirect) and make an ajax call instead, use the ajax call result to update the details div next to the clicked link.

You can put this code in your main view (or in an external js file without the `@section` part)

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("a.myClass").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                var $target = $(this).closest("div").find(".details");
                $.get(url,function(res) {
                        $target.html(res);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I have another follow-up question... Is it possible, from the above method, to pass along some route-values based on javascript values? I have two text fields with dates that I want to pass along to the same action...

Comment: Yes. you can update `url` variable in your js code with whatever route key-values you want.

Comment: How would that url variable be implemented, if lets say I have the javascript variables this.start and this.end? I extented your code with additional 2 route key-values: asp-route-start="" asp-route-end=""

Comment: If you have `asp-route-start` in your tag helper in the view, it will be int he url . If you want to add something else in the javascript, concatenate that before your ajax call.

Comment: I understand. But as you can see from the added lines, the asp-route start and end are set to = "". I want them to get the value from the javascript variables. What should they be set to equal?

Comment: You cannot keep JavaScript variable as asp-route-start as the tag helper gets executed in server before any JavaScript code execution in browser. You can update the URL varaiable value in JavaScript before the Ajax call to anything you want.

Comment: I created a button that sends an ajax GET request with two parameters (start, end date) to an action in my controller. The same viewcomponent is returned (I checked this with debugging). However, nothing on the page is updated after this ajax call. How should the javascript reload the view?

Comment: is it making the ajax call ? What is the response it is getting ? Are you updating the correct target DOM element on the success call back on the ajax call ?

Comment: I´ve placed an alert function within the "success" function, however nothing pops up. I guess the callback is not succeeded then? Please see my edit from the original post.

Comment: check your network tab to see the ajax call and see what response you are getting ? Is it a 200 OK,If not you need to fix that

Comment: We finally solved it. We added the start and end dates in the URL and it worked. Thank you so much!!